# I'm noob here. Need a little help to add values on EditText

Tags: android, addition

I've added a **spinner** in my Layout. I just want to add the EditText values **(abasic, ahra & aca)** and show the result on TextView **agross** with **calculate** button click how can I put java code for this???  I know how to create simple calculator but with these spinner codes I'm confused and if I type codes for **onButtonClick** method inside the main class It doesn't work. I guess something need to be done because of the **spinner** codes

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText abasic, ahra, aca, lopfd, lophd, la;
    TextView ebasic, ehra, eca, agross, egross, loprs, hdrs, lars, td, spd, eepf, erpf, tpf, eeesi, eresi, tesi, pfesi;
    Button calculate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] months = {"Select a month", "January", "February", "February(Leap Year)", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> monthadapter = new
                ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, months);

        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.month);
        dropdown.setAdapter((monthadapter));
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Access the values, convert to int, sum them, then assign to the other text view.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: How and where can I put code??? above spinner or below spinner?? I want to create OnButtonclick method for result with that button. Can you send me the code???

Comment: It doesn't matter where in the `onCreate()` method you add the Button click listener. Just put it after you found the Button by ID from the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using setOnClickListener to listen to click events

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText abasic, ahra, aca, lopfd, lophd, la;
    TextView ebasic, ehra, eca, agross, egross, loprs, hdrs, lars, td, spd, eepf, erpf, tpf, eeesi, eresi, tesi, pfesi;
    Button calculate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] months = {"Select a month", "January", "February", "February(Leap Year)", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> monthadapter = new
                ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, months);

        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.month);
        dropdown.setAdapter((monthadapter));


        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do your calculation
            }
        });
    }
}
```